# "MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request" when trying to upload file using javascript+ajax (works from postman)

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, multipartform-data

I am trying to create a web form that will allow uploading a single file from the browser to my own server.

The backend API is spring boot based, the specific controller was tested with postman and worked well. Now when I am trying to make the same for my website using JavaScript and ajax I get the following error:

1. Client side: Error 400 and

> ```
> > {"status":"NOT_FOUND","message":"Current request is not a multipart
> > request","timestamp":1604939158692}
> ```

2. server-side:

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request
> is not a multipart request

I have tried ~10 of the accepted solutions from other question on stackoverflow, but nothing helped.
These are the relevant code parts.

Spring controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/add_users_from_csv")
public ResponseEntity<String> addUsersListFromCSVFile(@PathVariable String id,  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("club") String clubId, @RequestParam("notifyByEmail") boolean notifyByEmail, @RequestParam("notifyBySMS")  boolean notifyBySMS) throws UnauthorizedRequestException {
    businessService.securityCheckID(id);
    return clubService.addUsersListFromCSVFile(clubId, file, notifyByEmail, notifyBySMS);
}
```

Client:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="uploadForm" id="fileUploadForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="Import""> 
        <input type="submit" value="Import" id="Import" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('form[name="uploadForm"]').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($('#fileUploadForm')[0]);
            formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]); 
            formData.append("club", "5cc5fd05569a720006169111");
            formData.append("notifyByEmail", "true");
            formData.append("notifyBySMS", "true");
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'http://localhost:8090/business/5cc625ed3ba686000665f111/add_users_from_csv',
                                    data: formData,
                                    type: "POST",
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false,
                                    cache: false,
                                    "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "bearer 0278e739-fbe0-4e3d-9acf-57544b011111"
  },
                                    success : function(response){
                                        alert(response); 
                                    },
                                    error: function(xhr,status,errorThrown) {
                                        alert(xhr.status); 
                                    }
                                });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Postman request (that works well with the same server):
[image]

[image]

What makes the request from browser fail and how to fix it please ?

Comment: Have you added a multipart configuration within your beans?

Comment: I followed the following article, and made adjustment to my project: https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload/.
I don't see any "multipart configuration" there. in addition, it worked with postman, isn't that mean configuration are properly set ?
can you please explain about your question ?

Comment: You set content-type of ajax request is  "Content-Type": "application/json",
check this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)